# using multiple json request with backbone.js

Tags: json, api, rest, backbone.js, routes

I have recently started working with backbone.js and i am finally started to get my head around after many tutorials.

One thing i am stuck on is how to use the routing to allow a list to pull different rest request.

Say i have the following in my collection

```
 var NewsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({  
          model : News,  
          url: 'http://api.example.com/index.php/news/all/format/json',  
        });
```

From my understanding correct me if i am wrong backbone stores all the data pulled from the above feed into my model that extends this collection, this will all work i will pull in the feed and then display it in the view

This is where i get confused within my routing i have the following.

```
var NewsRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                "": "defaultRoute",
                "news/:country_code":"updatedRoute"
            },

            defaultRoute: function () {
                console.log("defaultRoute");
                var movies = new NewsCollection()
                new NewsView({ collection: movies });
                movies.fetch();
                //setInterval(function(){movies.fetch({success: function(){}});}, 60000);
            },
            updatedRoute:function (country_code) {

                //confused
                    this.movie = this.movies.get(country_code);

            }

        })
```

I need to run the updatedRoute function when that will display a list of news based on cat of country code see below.
http://api.example.com/index.php/news/country/gb/format/json

How do i update the whole feed when a list item is click so the browser url would be.

```
http://localhost:8888/backbonetut/#news/gb
```

my list item is.

```
<li><a href='#news/gb'>GB</a></li>
```

I can get that in the updateRoute function with

```
this.movie = this.movies.get(country_code);
```

Can someone please help

Comment: that's easy. you will filter instead of get. _.filter(http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter) takes array of json and filters them down to matching set. You have to create a new variable to hold that set and pass that to the view that **can** display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either override the `fetch` function on your collection or temporarily change the `url` of the collection in your router action.